# Alternative to case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your suggestions on writing an SQL query other than using `CASE` statement in Oracle.I have a table named `SYSTEM_SPECS` with following data

```
Customer_Id     Disk_space_allocated
C001                    44G
C002                    1300G
C003                    1503G
C004                    1780G
```

I wrote following SQL query using Oracle case statement to get count of `customer_id` based on ranges for `disk_space_allocated`

```
select

  case

    when to_number(substr(disk_space_allocated,0,length(disk_space_allocated) -1  )) <= 300

    then '1-300'

    when to_number(substr(disk_space_allocated,0,length(disk_space_allocated) -1  )) <= 500

    then '300-500'

    when to_number(substr(disk_space_allocated,0,length(disk_space_allocated) -1 )) <= 700

    then '500-700'

    when to_number(substr(disk_space_allocated,0,length(disk_space_allocated) -1  )) <= 900

    then '700-900'

    else '900+'

  end      as diskallocated,

  count(*) as number_of_customers

from SYSTEM_SPECS

group by

  case

    when to_number(substr(disk_space_allocated,0,length(disk_space_allocated) -1 )) <= 300

    then '1-300'

    when to_number(substr(disk_space_allocated,0,length(disk_space_allocated) -1 )) <= 500

    then '300-500'

    when to_number(substr(disk_space_allocated,0,length(disk_space_allocated) -1 )) <= 700

    then '500-700'

    when to_number(substr(disk_space_allocated,0,length(disk_space_allocated) -1 )) <= 900

    then '700-900'

    else '900+'

  end;
```

Can this query be written is some other form?

Comment: you can have a table to store your ranges and join with it and then do a `PIVOT`

Comment: Why? What's the problem with `CASE`? It is verbose and easy to understand.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement. (It's a part of a query, i.e. case expression. Case statement is a stored procedure construction.)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your logic is wrong you are calculating <=700 and saying it between 500-700, if it is <=700 then by default it is <=500 and <=300. then we can not call it between 500-700. Try below query

```
select
  count(*) as number_of_customers,b.var as "Less Than below value"
from SYSTEM_SPECS a,
(select 300 + (level-1)*200 var
 from dual
connect by level <= 4) b
where to_number(substr(a.disk_space_allocated,0,length(a.disk_space_allocated) -1 )) <= b.var
group by b.var
order by b.var
```

Final answer for your question with the help of @Alex

```
with ranges as (
      select case when level = 1 then 0 else 100 end + (level-1) * 200 low_value,
        case when level = 5 then 99999999 else 100 + (level) * 200 end high_value
      from dual
      connect by level <= 5
    )
    select r.low_value ||'-'|| r.high_value as diskallocated,
      count(customer_id) as number_of_customers
    from ranges r
    left join system_specs ss
    on to_number(substr(ss.disk_space_allocated, 1, length(ss.disk_space_allocated) -1 )) > r.low_value
    and to_number(substr(ss.disk_space_allocated, 1, length(ss.disk_space_allocated) -1 )) <= r.high_value
    group by r.low_value, r.high_value
    order by r.low_value, r.high_value;
```

Comment: Here 500-700 means > 500 and <=700 and so on

Comment: See the second query in my comment. You might get some help.

Comment: The original logic isn't wrong; <=700 will give you between 500-700 because <=500 would have been matched by a previous condition. ('Between' is arguable as it's > 500 and <= 700; if they are integers I'd say 501-700). Your second query is close - fairly simple to [modify that to use the original ranges](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9158/1).